# Way to parse a string as a json dictionary key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there a way to parse a string as a chain of keys in a JSON dictionary?

For example, consider the below dictionary:-

```
person :{
 attributes : {
   gender: "F",
   height: 5.9,
   ...
 },
 functions : {
   eat : {
     enabled: true
     likes : ['pizza','ice-cream']
     dislikes : []
   },
   ...
 }
}
```

If I provide the keystring as

```
keystring="functions.eat.enabled"
```

Can I print the value from dictionary like below:

```
console.log(person[keystring]);
>> true
```

Comment: see `loadash.get`

Comment: have you tried testing it in the browser? A good place to find out would be [Try it online](https://tio.run/#javascript-v8)

Comment: @boxdox I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: @Razetime I meant something similar to the functionality... this will not work if I used this code. Apologies if that wasn't made clear on my end.